# How to make flexbox to support IE10 and Safari?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Right now I have this code:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The element centers on Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE10. I didn't check it yet on Safari and others browsers, but I want it to support them too. What should I add to this code?

Comment: You should be using auto margins for this sort of thing.  Don't try using CSS that is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @durbnpoisn It's actually also about to center vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need relevant vendor prefixes for IE10, Safari 8 and below, example:

```css
.my-class-name {

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

- Flexbox support tables: [caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- Autoprefixer: [autoprefixer.github.io](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)
- Prefixfree: [leaverou.github.io/prefixfree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)